# how to deal with mismatched tag bits in cache

Tags: cache

I was reading a textbook which describe general organization of cache as:
[image]

[image]

Then an exercise is, given `m=32`, `C = 1024`, `B = 8`,`E = 4`, `S = 32`, so `s = 5`, `b = 3`, therefore `t = 32-5-3 = 24`

I am a little bit confused here, since `E = 4`, we only need 2 bits to differentiate it, so `t` should be 2, if `t` is 24, isn't that we waste 22 bits?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63432627/340790 .

Answer (score 0):

For every cache set, there are $2^t$ blocks that can *potentially* be stored in there. However, only $E$ of them are *actually* stored at any particular time - typically, these would be the "most recently used" ones.

Incidentally, the whole reason for storing the tags themselves inside the cache is to be able to tell *which ones* are currently cached. The block's tag is not the "index" of a cache line, it's a $t$-bit identifier which is literally *compared* against every tag in the set in order to check whether this block is available or not.